# How to make the image texture flow perfectly from one mesh to another so that it looks seamless

Tags: mesh, texturing

I am designing a room that has non-conventional shapes. Curved walls, inset walls, island walls, etc. They are all separate meshes. I am using a plaster texture on the walls and I would like the image texture to flow seamlessly across all the meshes as if it was one solid mesh so that the texture flows in the same direction and to look as if the all the walls wall and each shift was plastered so you do not see seams. The meshes are using the same image texture. Is this possible? Images attached. Blender 3.3.1 [image: Room]

Comment: This is a situation where procedural textures excel, and image based ones are hard to make work